# The remix serve port is getting changed after changes in any file

Tags: typescript, remix

hi so i recently updated to `remix 2.3` from `remix 1.4` and the current issue that i have is whenever i change anything in any file the localhost port of remix serve changes so for example when i started the server with `npm run dev` it started on `http://localhost:63642` then i made changes in a component called `title.tsx` and it got changed to

```
[remix-serve] http://localhost:64000 (http://192.168.0.204:64000)
 info  app server ready (3.8s)
 info  hmr
```

my package.json scripts:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "remix build",
    "dev": "remix dev",
    "start": "remix-serve build",
    "test": "jest",
    "typecheck": "tsc"
  },
```

Comment: Maybe some other process that you initiated was using port 3000, so it chose a different port. happened to me once, Just had to go to task manager and release that port. then restarted my remix server.